# Как тип vector инициализировать от vector?

Tags: vector, c++

Вот способ, который пришел в голову, но первый вектор (iv) почему-то пустой.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> stringVector;
typedef std::vector<int> intVector;

intVector & StringVectorToIntVector(const stringVector strv){
intVector iv;

for (int i = 0; i < strv.size(); i++)
    iv.push_back(atoi(strv[i].c_str()));

   return iv;
}

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
stringVector v;
intVector iv;

v.push_back("10");
v.push_back("15");
v.push_back("20");

iv = StringVectorToIntVector(v);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: а как по другому вернуть вектор из функции, через параметр?

Comment: Я попробовал тестовую функцию написал. Она вернула мне 10

    int & func(){
 int a = 10;
 return a;
    }

Comment: @VladD спасибо. Вся нормальная документация на английском, а я немец. Поэтому все языки осваиваю методом экспирементов. Или русских мануалов. Про стек и хранения данных мало знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Вы создали вектор на стеке, и возвращаете ссылку на него. Так нельзя, объект умрёт после окончания работы функции.

Это компилируется, но неверно, и есть по стандарту undefined behaviour. Происходит что-то случайное. (С C++ не стоит полагаться на эксперимент, только на документацию.)

Возвращайте по значению, или передавайте ссылку на вектор в функцию.

А вообще-то, надо использовать [`std::transform`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) вот [так](http://ideone.com/wYeinQ) или даже вот [так](http://ideone.com/FchKXW).

**Обновление**

[[@perfect](/users/2872/perfect)](/users/2872/perfect): Ну, насчёт стека вам придётся разобраться, если вы программируете на низкоуровневом языке типа C++. Вкратце: локальные переменные функции умирают, когда функция заканчивается. Лишь возвращаемое значение копируется наружу. Ссылка не продлевает жизнь переменным (за исключением нескольких случаев, как обычно в C++). Так что возвращённая ссылка указывает на «труп».

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо, хороший человек. Запомнил.